# Tikz chain node loop to start of node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a node in a linked list and let it point back to itself.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
draw, rectangle split horizontal}, >=stealth, start chain]
  \node[list,on chain] (A) {1};
  \coordinate[above = 0.3 of A] (aa);

  \draw[*-] let \p1 = (A.two), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (A.east);

  \draw [-] (A.east) to[bend right=90] node[auto] {} (aa);
  \draw [->] (aa) to[bend right=90] node[auto] {} (A.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This results in the following image.

[image: Result]

But I would like it to be a nicer arrow like the following. A single arrow and it hits the item square on.

[image: Desired result]

Comment: A starting point: `\draw (A) to[out=0, in=0] (aa) to[out=180, in=180] (A);`

Comment: Another option, without the auxiliary node: `\draw [->] (A.east) -- +(5pt,0)  .. controls +(70:1) and +(100:1) .. ([xshift=-5pt]A.west) -- (A.west);`

Comment: And why chains?

Comment: @percusse, chains are in there because I started with an example of a linked list with more elements. So the chains is a remnant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `curve to` paths you can pass absolute angles directly with `in` and `out`.

```
\draw (A) to[out=0, in=0] ([shift=(up:.3)] A.north) to[out=180, in=180] (A);
```

Though I would use a different path and include the `*` arrow in it too. Using this in a `to path` style makes it easy to use repeatedly and as an edge.

The `\pgfextra` stuff is neccessary to carry the nodes on the edge to the horizontal part above the node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.multipart}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  dotloop above/.style={
    *->,
    looseness=#1,
    to path={
      \pgfextra{%
        \let\myTikZtostart\tikztostart
        \let\myTikZ@tonodes\tikz@tonodes
      }
      (\myTikZtostart.two |- \myTikZtostart.east) -- (\myTikZtostart.east) 
      to[out=0,in=0]  ([shift=(up:+.3cm)] \myTikZtostart.north east) -- ([shift=(up:+.3cm)] \myTikZtostart.north west)
      {\pgfextra{\tikz@node@is@a@labeltrue}\myTikZ@tonodes} to[out=180, in=180] (\myTikZtostart.west)
    }
  },
  dotloop above/.default=1.5,
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  list/.style={
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    draw,
    rectangle split horizontal},
  >=stealth,
  auto=right]

  \node[list] (A) {1};

  \path (A) edge[dotloop above] node {node} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Two options: the first one using the `controls` syntax and the other one using a decorated `ellipse` (I suppressed the `chain` since it was not necessary for the example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
list/.style={
  rectangle split,
  rectangle split parts=2,
  draw,
  rectangle split horizontal}, 
>=stealth
]
\node[list] (A) {1};
\draw[*-] (A.two|-A.center) -- (A.east);
\draw [->] (A.east) -- +(5pt,0) .. controls +(70:1) and +(100:1) ..   
  ([xshift=-5pt]A.west) -- (A.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
list/.style={
  rectangle split,
  rectangle split parts=2,
  draw,
  rectangle split horizontal}, 
>=stealth
]
\draw[decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.62 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction=decorate] 
  ([yshift=8pt]A.center) ellipse [x radius=19pt,y radius=10pt];
\node[list,fill=white] (A) {1};
\draw[*-] (A.two|-A.center) -- (A.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The output of the other solution is closer to what I want so I accepted that one.